# Prevent HTML Form Tampering with ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I know this question has been asked a lot, for example this one: [How to make sure elements of HTML form have not been changed in purpose of hacking on client side before submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281544/how-to-make-sure-elements-of-html-form-have-not-been-changed-in-purpose-of-hacki)

Now **I am thinking to generate a salted hash sum for every html form to ensure the form has not been tampered with**.

But before I do this is there any built-in (ASP.NET) annotation/framework that does this? I know there is `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` annotation but this is to solve different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why just not use SSL? Generating hash for every element does not change anything, because hacker will have to do the same. SSL will give you much more probably that everything is exactly same as client send. Of course it can be [Man-in-the-middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), but it is much more difficult to create.

Comment: SSL really isn't a solution here - it makes no difference if the tampered with form is transmitted via SSL or not. It still is a tampered form.